# Suggestions for appropriate transformations for Multiple Regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-transformation

My residual plots look like this for each predictor: Does anyone have suggestions on transformations? I tried log transformations but some of my predictors have 0 so it doesn't work.
Scatter plots for each predictor:
[image]
Residual plots for each predictor:
[image]

Comment: Note that transformations are performed on the original variable, so what do the plots of $y$ vs $x_i$ look like? (you might also like to consider smaller plots, perhaps in a 2x2 grid). It's possible that some other strategy that transformation may be better.

Comment: @Glen_b I revised my question. What else can I do besides transformations? I took a basic regressions course but I don't think we went over anything else. Actually in a different question I asked with similar data, as Y also being expenditure, someone suggested I use a different model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to transform, I wouldn't transform everything.

The response looks like a log-transform would be reasonable for it.

It might make sense to log-transform `ccap` and *maybe* some transformation of `workdays` (not necessarily log; I'd want to see something like how a partial residual plot against `workdays` looked).

Alternatively, I'd consider a Gamma GLM with log-link, and again, maybe consider a log-transform for `ccap` and possibly some transformation of workdays.